# Cancel / Ignore valueChanged on Enter

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

How can I cancel / block or ignore the `valueChanged()` event in a spin box when enter key is pressed?

Having multiple double spin-boxes in a group that are updated when one is changed.

```
[spin1] [spin2]
```

When `spin1` emits the `valueChanged()` event, I update the value of `spin2` and vice versa. However: if Enter key is pressed, the value should not be updated.

E.g. user types *250* in *spin1*, press Tab so that *spin2* get focus. Then press Enter. Now *spin1* should not be updated (as value of *spin2* has not been changed).

Connected as:

```
self.spin1.valueChanged.connect(self.update_values)
self.spin2.valueChanged.connect(self.update_values)
```

Answer (score -1):

One option is to get the `lineEdit` object of the spin-box and check `isModified()`

It will not block the signal, but it is at least a way of filtering out the event and can be applied in `update_values`.

Comment: Although this will work, the correct way to solve it to use [setKeyboardTracking](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractspinbox.html#keyboardTracking-prop). At first glance, this might not seem to give you what you want - but I think if you try it, you will see that it gives much more predictable behaviour. Specifically, it only ever emits one signal per value change.

Comment: @ekhumoro: One issue is that this is a dialog with a `QDialogButtonBox` which means that Enter "submits" the dialog in any input field. Thus if user put a value in `spin1` tabs to `spin2` and press enter, the value of `spin1` is updated as dialog closes which is not desired.

Comment: My "answer" has its issues, yes. So I'll delete it. E.g. is `isModified` false when up/down key or spinarrows are pressed

Comment: Is that behaviour of the Enter key what you want? It seems very user-unfriendly. Why not just assign a different shortcut for submitting the dialog?

Comment: @ekhumoro: No. I do not want it to be. Looking to change that as well. I have connected to `accepted()` and `rejected()`. In the `acepted` method I close the window. But this function is called on Enter as well (Not only when OK is clicked or Alt+O is pressed (The kbd-shortcut)). Have not found a way to detect what method was used though.

Comment: To change the behaviour when pressing Enter in a dialog, see the docs for [setDefault](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html#default-prop) and [setAutoDefault](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html#autoDefault-prop).